# How do I find out when debian packages were last updated?

Tags: debian, ubuntu-10.04, debian-based

I access an ubuntu 10.04LTS server that is administered by someone else, I have a feeling that it hasn't been getting updates/upgrades recently.

Is there a way to check on the command line when updates were last taken, without sudo privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If permissions haven't changed from default an unprivledge user in Ubuntu can read the apt history log:

```
less /var/log/apt/history.log
```

If you just care about how often you can:

```
grep Start-Date /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Comment: Then a update hasn't happened recently.
There are gziped versions of the older log files as gistory.log.1.gz to history.log.10.gz.  You could copy them into your home directory, ungzip them and the the above grep on them.